# Node: HTTPS server stops working with EADDRINUSE error

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, https

I have set up a Node and Express HTTPS server on a Raspbian machine as follows:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const https = require('https');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const upload = multer();
const app = express();
const codes = require('./codes.js');

let privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/home/pi/Desktop/padscape/server/private.key', 'utf-8');
let certificate = fs.readFileSync('/home/pi/Desktop/padscape/server/server.cert', 'utf-8');
let credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify({'Error': 'Bad Request'}));
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname, {dotfiles: 'allow'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/code', codes);
app.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
});

let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

I want to start the server on boot so I have added this to `/home/pi/.bashrc`:

```sh
echo "RUNNING ON BOOT"
sudo fuser 443/tcp
sudo node /home/pi/Desktop/padscape/server/app.js &> ~/padscape_log.txt &
```

When I start up my Raspberry Pi I see the following error on the error log:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::443
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1309:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1445:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Desktop/padscape/server/app.js:31:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1336:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 443
}
```

I have tried to change the port from 443 to 8443 with no success. As you can see, `sudo fuser 443/tcp` is supposed to kill all the services in port 443. What should I do?

Comment: I have tried most solutions I have found in related StackOverflow questions.

Comment: It seems to me that I must find a different way to run the server on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I shouldn't be running the file from `.bashrc`. This file may run on startup, but it also runs when I opened a new command line terminal! I was using several terminals at once and this caused several errors! So, I removed my command from `.bashrc` and used `/etc/rc.local` to run it instead.